# Set difference with NaN values

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples that may contain `NaN` values. And I want to see the difference between these two lists.

For example, I have two sets like these:

```py
In [1]: set1 = set([(1, 2, float('nan')), (1, 2, 3)])                          
In [2]: set2 = set([(1, 2, float('nan')), (1, 2, 3)])
```

To me, these sets seem equal, but to Python, they seem not:

```py
In [3]: set1 == set2                                                           
Out[3]: False
```

And if I check their difference, it gives me the first tuple:

```py
In [4]: set1.difference(set2)                                                  
Out[4]: {(1, 2, nan)}
In [5]: set2.difference(set1)                                                  
Out[5]: {(1, 2, nan)}
```

How can I ask Python to kindly consider these sets equal?

I cannot remove these `NaN` values and then check for their difference, because I'm retrieving them from a `Pandas DataFrame` and the values can either be `NaN` or not.

My desired output is something like this:

```py
In [1]: set1 = set([(1, 2, float('nan')), (1, 2, 3)])
In [2]: set2 = set([(1, 2, float('nan')), (1, 2, 3)])
In [3]: set2.difference(set1)                                                 
Out[3]: set()
In [4]: set1.difference(set2)                                                 
Out[4]: set()

In [5]: set1 = set([(1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 3)])                                    
In [6]: set2 = set([(1, 2, float('nan')), (1, 2, 3)])                         
In [7]: set2.difference(set1)                                                 
Out[7]: {(1, 2, nan)}
In [8]: set1.difference(set2)                                                 
Out[8]: {(1, 2, 5)}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: See if this helps: https://towardsdatascience.com/navigating-the-hell-of-nans-in-python-71b12558895b

Comment: [`math.isnan()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) could be helpful, too.